# Exchange sacrifice to dominate black squares in Najdorf

Tags: master-games, najdorf

My question is a bit ambiguous and not that specific (it wouldn't be if I could remember more details):

I'm looking for a Najdorf game played against Lazaro Bruzon (or against Lenier?) probably around 10 years ago. Black sacrificed a rook for the black-squared bishop and then black dominated all the black squares. I think white played the English attack (Be3) and black replied e5. I also remember that the rook went to c4 and then e4 to capture the bishop in e3, if I'm not wrong. Can someone help me find this game?

Thank you!

Comment: So, Bruzon (or Dominguez) was white? Do you remember who won the game, black or white?

Comment: http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1366555

Comment: Right! that's the one.

Answer (score 2):

I found it! It was Lazaro Bruzon vs Vassily Ivanchuk, 11/2005. Here's the link to the game (totally recommended!): 
http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chessgame?gid=1366555

Thank you for the help!